# Using mysql user defined variables with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL statement which runs perfectly when used on phpmyadmin,

```
$q1 = " SET @pos = 0;  UPDATE `songs` SET `tweek` = ( @pos:= @pos+1) WHERE `approved` = 1 ORDER BY votes DESC ";
```

my connection is fine, every other thing is fine but I keep getting an error when I use it in my php code.

```
mysql_query($q1, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE `songs` SET `tweek` = 1 WHERE `approved` = 1 ORDER BY
>   votes DESC' at line 1

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SET and UPDATE are two queries and you must split it into two different calls of mysql_query